# How to run a bigger batch with AWS SageMaker Batch Transform

Tags: xgboost, amazon-sagemaker

I created an XGBoost model with AWS SageMaker. Now I'm trying to use it through Batch Transform Job, and it's all going pretty well for small batches.

However, there's a slightly bigger batch of 600.000 rows in a ~16MB file and I can't manage to run it in one go. I tried two things:

1.

Setting 'Max payload size' of the Transform job to its maximum (100 MB):

```
transformer = sagemaker.transformer.Transformer(
    model_name = config.model_name,
    instance_count = config.inference_instance_count,
    instance_type = config.inference_instance_type,
    output_path = "s3://{}/{}".format(config.bucket, config.s3_inference_output_folder),
    sagemaker_session = sagemaker_session,
    base_transform_job_name = config.inference_job_prefix,
    max_payload = 100
    )
```

However, I still get an error (through console CloudWatch logs):

```
413 Request Entity Too Large
The data value transmitted exceeds the capacity limit.
```

2.

Setting max_payload to 0, which, by specification, Amazon SageMaker should interpret as no limit on the payload size.

In that case the job finishes successfully, but the output file is empty (0 bytes).

Any ideas either what I'm doing wrong, or how to run a bigger batch?

Comment: Have you been able to solve this issue? My batch prediction output keeps outputting 0 bytes object. I have tried the bottom solutions. Still don't work...

Answer (score 6):

Most of SageMaker algorithms set their own default execution parameters with 6 MB in MaxPayloadInMB, so if you are getting 413 from SageMaker algorithms, you are likely to be exceeding the maximum payload they can support. Assuming each row is less than 6 MB in the file, you can fix this by leaving MaxPayloadInMB unset to fallback to the algorithm's default size and setting SplitType to "Line" instead, so it can split the data into smaller batches (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/API_TransformInput.html#SageMaker-Type-TransformInput-SplitType).

Answer (score 3):

this helped me resolve the issue by setting `strategy='SingleRecord'` in the `transformer` + you can also add a stronger instance via `instance_type` and distribute via `instance_count`.

Comment: I have tried this method, but the .transform() process returns "Internal server error"... Have you encountered this error by any chance?

Comment: @Bilguun how did you resolve the "Internal server error". I am facing the same issue

Answer (score 0):

I have tried the above solutions, but unfortunately they didn't work for me.

Here is what worked for me: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55920737/7091978

Basically, I set "max_payload" from 0 to 1.

Answer (score 0):

I think max payload is limited anyway at Sagemaker side. So your max payload size is limited somewhere below 100MB (as far as I know, for KNN - it was 6MB as defulat)
Workaround is using `SplitType` when execute transformer job depending on your content type (`TFRecord` or `RecordIO`)

`transformer.transform([your data path], content_type='application/x-recordio-protobuf',split_type='TFRecord')`

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/APIReference/API_TransformInput.html

Then you can seamlessly transform a data bigger than 6MB.