# Errors running Sagemaker Batch Transformation with LDA model

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-sagemaker, protobuf-c

I've successfully trained a LDA model with sagemaker, I've been able to set up an Inference API but it has a limit of how many records I can query at a time.

I need to get predictions for a large file and have been trying to use Batch Transformation however am running against roadblock.

My input date is in application/x-recordio-protobuf content type, code is as follows:

```
# Initialize the transformer object
transformer =sagemaker.transformer.Transformer(
    base_transform_job_name='Batch-Transform',
    model_name=model_name,
    instance_count=1,
    instance_type='ml.c4.xlarge',
    output_path=output_location,
    max_payload=20,
    strategy='MultiRecord'
    )
# Start a transform job
transformer.transform(input_location, content_type='application/x-recordio-protobuf',split_type="RecordIO")
# Then wait until the transform job has completed
transformer.wait()

# Fetch validation result 
s3_client.download_file(bucket, 'topic_model_batch_transform/output/batch_tansform_part0.pbr.out', 'batch_tansform-result')
with open('batch_tansform-result') as f:
    results = f.readlines()   
print("Sample transform result: {}".format(results[0]))
```

I have chunked by input file into 10 files each around 19MB in size. I am attempting at first to run on a single chunk, therefore 19MB in total. I have tried changing strategy, trying SingleRecord. I have also tried different split_types, also trying None and "Line".

I've read the documentation but its not clear what else I should try, also the error messages are very unclear.

```
2019-04-02T15:49:47.617:[sagemaker logs]: MaxConcurrentTransforms=1, MaxPayloadInMB=20, BatchStrategy=MULTI_RECORD
#011at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)2019-04-02T15:49:48.035:[sagemaker logs]: du-sagemaker/data/batch_transform/batch_tansform_part0.pbr: Bad HTTP status returned from invoke: 413
2019-04-02T15:49:48.036:[sagemaker logs]: du-sagemaker/data/batch_transform/batch_tansform_part0.pbr:
2019-04-02T15:49:48.036:[sagemaker logs]: du-sagemaker/data/batch_transform/batch_tansform_part0.pbr: Message:
2019-04-02T15:49:48.036:[sagemaker logs]: du-sagemaker/data/batch_transform/batch_tansform_part0.pbr: <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 3.2 Final//EN">
2019-04-02T15:49:48.036:[sagemaker logs]: du-sagemaker/data/batch_transform/batch_tansform_part0.pbr: <title>413 Request Entity Too Large</title>
2019-04-02T15:49:48.036:[sagemaker logs]: du-sagemaker/data/batch_transform/batch_tansform_part0.pbr: <h1>Request Entity Too Large</h1>
2019-04-02T15:49:48.036:[sagemaker logs]: du-sagemaker/data/batch_transform/batch_tansform_part0.pbr: <p>The data value transmitted exceeds the capacity limit.</p>
```

The above is the last one I got with the above configuration, before that I was also getting a 400 HTTP error code.

Any help or pointers would be greatly appreciated! Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to resolve the issue, it seemed the maxpayload I was using was too high. I set  `MaxPayloadInMB=1` and it now runs like a dream

Answer (score 2):

While the Batch Transform platform supports flexible payload limits (via `MaxPayloadInMB`), many algorithms set more strict internal limits. This is true for the SageMaker built-in LDA algorithm which rejects "large" requests according to its internal configuration.

The error you see in the log says exactly this: the Batch Transform client attempted to send a request as large as 20MB, but the LDA algorithm server rejected the request with error code `413 (Request Entity Too Large)`.

When using a SageMaker built-in algorithm container, or any container that is not your own, we recommend leaving the parameter `MaxPayloadInMB` unset in your `CreateTransformJob` request. This will prompt the platform to choose the algorithm's default execution parameters, which you will see printed in your log like so:

```
[sagemaker logs]: MaxConcurrentTransforms=1, MaxPayloadInMB=${DEFAULT_MAX_PAYLOAD_IN_MB}, BatchStrategy=MultiRecord
```

For more insight on how these "execution parameters" are resolved, see the "order of precedence" documented [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/your-algorithms-batch-code.html#your-algorithms-batch-code-how-containe-serves-requests).

Aside from controlling payload size, your other transform job parameter choices (`SplitType=RecordIO` and `BatchStrategy=MultiRecord`) look correct for passing RecordIO-Protobuf data.