# Batch transform sparse matrix with AWS SageMaker Python SDK

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, scikit-learn, sparse-matrix, amazon-sagemaker

I have successfully trained a Scikit-Learn LSVC model with AWS SageMaker.
I want to make batch prediction (aka. batch transform) on a relatively big dataset which is a scipy sparse matrix with shape 252772 x 185128. (The number of features is high because there is one-hot-encoding of bag-of-words and ngrams features).

I struggle because of:

- the size of the data
- the format of the data

I did several experiments to check what was going on:

#### 1. predict locally on sample sparse matrix data

**It works**
Deserialize the model artifact locally on a SageMaker notebook and predict on a sample of the sparse matrix.
This was just to check that the model can predict on this kind of data.

#### 2. Batch Transform on a sample csv data

**It works**
Launch a Batch Transform Job on SageMaker and request to transform a small sample in dense csv format : it works but does not scale, obviously.
The code is:

```py
sklearn_model = SKLearnModel(
    model_data=model_artifact_location_on_s3,
    entry_point='my_script.py',
    role=role,
    sagemaker_session=sagemaker_session)

transformer = sklearn_model.transformer(
   instance_count=1, 
   instance_type='ml.m4.xlarge', 
   max_payload=100)

transformer.transform(
   data=batch_data, 
   content_type='text/csv',
   split_type=None)   

print('Waiting for transform job: ' + transformer.latest_transform_job.job_name)
transformer.wait()
```

where:

- 'my_script.py' implements a simple `model_fn` to deserialize the model artifact:

```py
def model_fn(model_dir):
    clf = joblib.load(os.path.join(model_dir, "model.joblib"))
    return clf
```

- `batch_data` is the s3 path for the csv file.

#### 3. Batch Transform of a sample dense numpy dataset.

**It works**
I prepared a sample of the data and saved it to s3 in Numpy `.npy` format. According to [this documentation](https://sagemaker.readthedocs.io/en/stable/using_sklearn.html#sagemaker-scikit-learn-model-server), SageMaker Scikit-learn model server can deserialize NPY-formatted data (along with JSON and CSV data).
The only difference with the previous experiment (2) is the argument `content_type='application/x-npy'` in `transformer.transform(...)`.

This solution does not scale and we would like to pass a Scipy sparse matrix:

#### 4. Batch Transform of a big sparse matrix.

**Here is the problem**
SageMaker Python SDK does not support sparse matrix format out of the box.
Following this:

- https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/machine-learning/build-a-movie-recommender-with-factorization-machines-on-amazon-sagemaker/
- [Errors running Sagemaker Batch Transformation with LDA model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55479366/errors-running-sagemaker-batch-transformation-with-lda-model)

I used `write_spmatrix_to_sparse_tensor` to write the data to protobuf format on s3. The function I used is:

```py
def write_protobuf(X_sparse, bucket, prefix, obj):
    """Write sparse matrix to protobuf format at location bucket/prefix/obj."""
    buf = io.BytesIO()
    write_spmatrix_to_sparse_tensor(file=buf, array=X_sparse, labels=None)
    buf.seek(0)
    key = '{}/{}'.format(prefix, obj)
    boto3.resource('s3').Bucket(bucket).Object(key).upload_fileobj(buf)
    return 's3://{}/{}'.format(bucket, key)
```

Then the code used for launching the batch transform job is:

```py
sklearn_model = SKLearnModel(
    model_data=model_artifact_location_on_s3,
    entry_point='my_script.py',
    role=role,
    sagemaker_session=sagemaker_session)

transformer = sklearn_model.transformer(
   instance_count=1, 
   instance_type='ml.m4.xlarge', 
   max_payload=100)

transformer.transform(
   data=batch_data, 
   content_type='application/x-recordio-protobuf',
   split_type='RecordIO')   

print('Waiting for transform job: ' + transformer.latest_transform_job.job_name)
transformer.wait()
```

I get the following error:

```
sagemaker_containers._errors.ClientError: Content type application/x-recordio-protobuf is not supported by this framework.
```

**Questions:**
(Reference doc for Transformer: https://sagemaker.readthedocs.io/en/stable/transformer.html)

- If `content_type='application/x-recordio-protobuf'` is not allowed, what should I use?
- Is `split_type='RecordIO'` the proper setting in this context?
- Should I provide an `input_fn` function in my script to deserialize the data?
- Is there another better approach to tackle this problem?

Comment: corresponding issue on github with reactions: https://github.com/aws/sagemaker-python-sdk/issues/1093